# Find missing records in joined table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's say I have 3 tables in SQL Server 2008, `Users`, `Site` and `UserSite`:

```
+-------+    +-------+    +-------------+
| User  |    | Site  |    |  User Site  |
+-------+    +-------+    +-------------+
| User1 |    | Site1 |    | User1 Site1 |
| User2 |    | Site2 |    | User1 Site2 |
| User3 |    +-------+    | User1 Site3 |
+-------+                 | User2 Site1 |
                          | User2 Site3 |
                          | User3 Site1 |
                          +-------------+
```

Desired result: for each `User` and `Site` combo there has to be a record in `UserSite` like this:

```
+-------------+
|  User Site  |
+-------------+
| User1 Site1 |
| User1 Site2 |
| User1 Site3 |
| User2 Site1 |
|*User2 Site2*| Inserted
| User2 Site3 |
| User3 Site1 |
|*User3 Site2*| Inserted
|*User3 Site3*| Inserted
+-------------+
```

I can only Insert new records and cannot rewrite table from scratch.

Is there a way to do this with SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might suggest a brute force approach.  Truncate the table and insert all the values:

```
truncate table UserSite;

insert into UserSite(User, Site)
    select u.user, s.site
    from users u cross join sites s;
```

You can just add the new ones with a slightly more complex query:

```
insert into UserSite(User, Site)
    select u.user, s.site
    from users u cross join
         sites s
    where not exists (select 1
                      from usersite us
                      where us.user = u.user and us.site = s.site
                     );
```

Comment: I cannot truncate table. Second query might work, I'll try it out now

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @Gordon Why is your second query preferable to a left outer join to the "User Site" table where the User Site table's field is null?

Comment: @StanShaw . . . It doesn't make a difference.  The two are semantically the same and which if one is faster, that is the fault of the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Cross JOIN**

```
SELECT 
*
FROM Users
CROSS JOIN Site
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the missing records to be selected, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
CROSS JOIN Site 

EXCEPT

SELECT *
FROM UserSite
```